# Issue saving data to Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am having a very frustrating issue trying to get my data saved to Parse.

Typically, this has been the easiest sections for me to do, but this instance is getting the best of me.

I have search A LOT trying to find where the issue could be, but no luck.  No data is being sent to Parse (actually back4apps.com)

Person is a class created to save the records locally.

```
func saveToParse () {

    let addressQuery = PFQuery(className: "addressBook")

    print ("Saved UUID to Parse is: \(addressUUID)")

    if person!.uuid != nil
    {
        print ("Has UUID")

    addressQuery.whereKey("uuid", equalTo: person!.uuid!)
    addressQuery.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error != nil {

            if let object = objects {

                object.valueForKey("firstName")?.setValue(self.nameField.text!, forKey: "firstName")
                object.valueForKey("lastName")?.setValue(self.lastNameField.text!, forKey: "lastName")
                object.valueForKey("phone")?.setValue(self.phoneField.text!, forKey: "phone")
                object.valueForKey("email")?.setValue(self.emailField.text!, forKey: "email")
                object.valueForKey("addressCity")?.setValue(self.addressCityField.text!, forKey: "addressCity")
                object.valueForKey("addressCountry")?.setValue(self.addressCountryField.text!, forKey: "addressCountry")
                object.valueForKey("entryFrom")?.setValue("Divelog Update", forKey: "entryFrom")

                let addressBookImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.addressBookImageAdd!.image!, 0.5)
                let addressBookImageFile = PFFile(name: "addressBookImage.jpg", data: addressBookImageData!)
                object ["addressBookImage"] = addressBookImageFile

//                    object.saveEventually()

                object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if (success) {
                        print ("parse save successful")
                    } else {
                        print ("parse failed")
                        print (error)
                    }
                }



        } else {
            print (error)
            }
        }
    }
    } else {

        print ("No UUID found")

        let addressObject = PFObject(className: "addressBook")

        addressObject["firstName"]          = self.nameField.text!
        addressObject["lastName"]           = self.lastNameField.text!
        addressObject["phone"]              = self.phoneField.text!
        addressObject["email"]              = self.emailField.text!
        addressObject["addressCity"]        = self.addressCityField.text!
        addressObject["addressCountry"]     = self.addressCountryField.text!
        addressObject["username"]           = PFUser.currentUser()!.username
        addressObject["uuid"]               = addressUUID
        addressObject["entryFrom"]          = "Divelog New"

        let addressBookImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.addressBookImageAdd!.image!, 0.5)
        let addressBookImageFile = PFFile(name: "addressBookImage.jpg", data: addressBookImageData!)
        addressObject ["addressBookImage"] = addressBookImageFile

//            addressObject.saveEventually()

        addressObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {
                print ("parse save successful")
            } else {
                print ("parse failed")
                print (error)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Also, this app has 2 other sections that are sending data to Parse successfully.  It is only an issue with the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code is getting an `AnyObject` from the value, then setting another value to that `AnyObject`

```
object.valueForKey("firstName")?.setValue(self.nameField.text!, forKey: "firstName")
```

You probably want to set the value to your original object. Replace the above line with this:

```
object.setValue(self.nameField.text!, forKey: "firstName")
```

Comment: @DavidSanford glad to help